# V.Clean is not giving output In QGIS 3.14 Pi

Tags: qgis-3, grass-gis, kml, slivers, v.clean

I was trying to clean by removing sliver lines between set of polygons in my KML file. But unfortunately I am getting following error:

```
QGIS version: 3.14.15-Pi
QGIS code revision: d5114d2cfa
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 3.0.4
GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'v.clean' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-b' : False, '-c' : False, 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : 1, 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '', 'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT' : False, 'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '', 'error' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'input' : 'memory://MultiPolygonZ?crs=EPSG:4326&field=Name:string(0,0)&field=description:string(0,0)&field=timestamp:datetime(0,0)&field=begin:datetime(0,0)&field=end:datetime(0,0)&field=altitudeMode:string(0,0)&field=tessellate:integer(0,0)&field=extrude:integer(0,0)&field=visibility:integer(0,0)&field=drawOrder:integer(0,0)&field=icon:string(0,0)&uid={b42a2f19-1fa1-47f8-b165-7ca7dd6fd651}', 'output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'threshold' : '', 'tool' : [0], 'type' : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] }

g.proj -c proj4="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=1.0 input="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_oQspqW\d760590c414246c889fbe8b2e6cb1909\input.shp" output="vector_5f941a888fecf5" --overwrite -o
g.region n=11.33889471711012 s=11.13167449885797 e=76.17858259071603 w=75.95686615763981
v.clean input=vector_5f941a888fecf5 type="point,line,boundary,centroid,area,face,kernel" tool="break" output=output4520ba735e2844949715fdd7de593a69 error=error4520ba735e2844949715fdd7de593a69 --overwrite
v.out.ogr type="auto" input="output4520ba735e2844949715fdd7de593a69" output="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_oQspqW\fe8e3a7a942f4771a7c8f7c208ddd4e0\output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
v.out.ogr type="auto" input="error4520ba735e2844949715fdd7de593a69" output="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_oQspqW\cd3d13f42e84401eb6f7d9533948c72d\error.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
Starting GRASS GIS...
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
Cleaning up temporary files...
Executing <C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_oQspqW\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> ...
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents>chcp 1252 1>NUL
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents>g.proj -c proj4="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default
Projection information updated
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents>v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=1.0 input="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_oQspqW\d760590c414246c889fbe8b2e6cb1909\input.shp" output="vector_5f941a888fecf5" --overwrite -o
Over-riding projection check
Check if OGR layer <input> contains polygons...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Creating attribute table for layer <input>...
Importing 151 features (OGR layer <input>)...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Registering primitives...
-----------------------------------------------------
Cleaning polygons
-----------------------------------------------------
Snapping boundaries (threshold = 1.000e+000)...
Reading features...
Snap vertices Pass 1: select points
0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100
Snap vertices Pass 2: assign anchor vertices
4..9..14..19..24..29..34..39..44..49..54..59..64..69..74..79..84..89..94..99..100
Snap vertices Pass 3: snap to assigned points
0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Breaking polygons...
Breaking polygons (pass 1: select break points)...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
Breaking polygons (pass 2: break at selected points)...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing duplicates...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Breaking boundaries...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing duplicates...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Cleaning boundaries at nodes...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Merging boundaries...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing dangles...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Building areas...
0..-----------------------------------------------------
Removing bridges...
2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Registering primitives...
-----------------------------------------------------
Finding centroids for OGR layer <input>...
0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Writing centroids...
-----------------------------------------------------
227 input polygons
Total area: 0 (0 areas)
-----------------------------------------------------
Copying features...
Building topology for vector map <vector_5f941a888fecf5@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
-----------------------------------------------------
227 input polygons got lost during import.
The snapping threshold 1 might be too large.
Estimated range of snapping threshold: [0, 0]
Try to reduce the snapping threshold or clean the output manually.
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents>g.region n=11.33889471711012 s=11.13167449885797 e=76.17858259071603 w=75.95686615763981
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents>v.clean input=vector_5f941a888fecf5 type="point,line,boundary,centroid,area,face,kernel" tool="break" output=output4520ba735e2844949715fdd7de593a69 error=error4520ba735e2844949715fdd7de593a69 --overwrite
Note: In latitude-longitude coordinate system specify threshold in degree unit
--------------------------------------------------
Tool: Threshold
Break: 0
--------------------------------------------------
Copying features...
Rebuilding parts of topology...
Building topology for vector map <output4520ba735e2844949715fdd7de593a69@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
--------------------------------------------------
Tool: Break lines at intersections
100
--------------------------------------------------
Rebuilding topology for output vector map...
Building topology for vector map <output4520ba735e2844949715fdd7de593a69@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
--------------------------------------------------
Building topology for error vector map...
Building topology for vector map <error4520ba735e2844949715fdd7de593a69@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents>v.out.ogr type="auto" input="output4520ba735e2844949715fdd7de593a69" output="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_oQspqW\fe8e3a7a942f4771a7c8f7c208ddd4e0\output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
WARNING: Unable to determine input map's vector feature type(s).
WARNING: Vector map <output4520ba735e2844949715fdd7de593a69> is 3D. Use format specific layer creation options (parameter 'lco') to export <in 3D rather than 2D (default).
WARNING: Output layer is empty, no features written
v.out.ogr complete. 0 features (Unknown (any) type) written to <output4520ba735e2844949715fdd7de593a69> (GPKG format).
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents>v.out.ogr type="auto" input="error4520ba735e2844949715fdd7de593a69" output="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_oQspqW\cd3d13f42e84401eb6f7d9533948c72d\error.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
WARNING: Unable to determine input map's vector feature type(s).
WARNING: Vector map <error4520ba735e2844949715fdd7de593a69> is 3D. Use format specific layer creation options (parameter 'lco') to export <in 3D rather than 2D (default).
WARNING: No attribute table found -> using only category numbers as attributes
WARNING: Output layer is empty, no features written
v.out.ogr complete. 0 features (Unknown (any) type) written to <error4520ba735e2844949715fdd7de593a69> (GPKG format).
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents>exit
Execution of <C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_oQspqW\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> finished.
Cleaning up default sqlite database ...
Cleaning up temporary files...
Execution completed in 122.02 seconds
Results:
{'error': 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\processing_oQspqW\\cd3d13f42e84401eb6f7d9533948c72d\\error.gpkg',
'output': 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\processing_oQspqW\\fe8e3a7a942f4771a7c8f7c208ddd4e0\\output.gpkg'}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'v.clean' finished
```

Comment: "I'm getting following error." - which one actually? Note that v.clean creates two maps: one with the clean vectors, on with the error vectors. See https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/v.clean.html

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Manoj K E Manoj. analyzing the log from v.clean I saw these lines of information:
`g.proj -c proj4="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs" and g.region n=11.33889471711012 s=11.13167449885797 e=76.17858259071603 w=75.95686615763981`, this way, I suposed that your kml data is in an geographic coordinate system, it's right?

Comment: So, moving along, I've found another interesting line in your log:
`227 input polygons got lost during import.
The snapping threshold 1 might be too large.`
This message means that your data was snapping/cleaning with 1 degree of distance (111.32 km +-), in other words, it's ripping out all of your data. I suggest you convert your data to UTM coordinate system or try to put a little tiny value in the threshold field (0.0001° = 11.1 m e.g.) to see if it produces any results.

Comment: @FranciscoCamello Yes, this is a geographic system with multiple polygon. I tried by giving threshold as .001. But no result.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "removing sliver line". The `v.clean` tool has a method called `rmsa` = remove small angles between lines at nodes. In your `v.clean` command above you are asking for  only one clean command `break`. I doubt that is what you want here.  And, as Francisco Camello pointed out, you will definitely need to add the `threshold` parameter to `v.clean` with some very small value, appropriate to the features in your layer.

Comment: @Micha I was trying to remove gaps between polygons

Comment: Ah, that's a different story `v.clean` corrects topology errors. Gaps are not errors :-)

Comment: Please help me on this, to remove gaps between polygons

Comment: @ManojKEManoj ```v.clean``` removes gaps between polygons, take a look at this image ![V_clean](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v_clean.png). The v.clean uses the threshold to snap vertices too, take a look at ![the documentation](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.clean.html), there are some useful examples, maybe help you.

Comment: @FranciscoCamello. Thanks a lot. Its working now. Problem was with the values given in the tolerance.